# Subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

**Question:** Among all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $\mathbb{Z}$, does there exists a maximal (proper) subgroup?

I have proved these facts:

**(1)** $\mathbb{Q}$ has no maximal (proper) subgroup.

**(2)** $\mathbb{Q}$ is not finitely generated.

**(3)** If $G$ is any group, $H$ is a proper subgroup, and $S$ is a finite subset of $G$ such that $H$ and $S$ generate $G$ ($\langle H,S\rangle=G$) then $G$ has a maximal subgroup containing $H$.

I went into both YES and NO answers several times by the above three facts. Any suggestion for question?

Comment: In what sense do you want your subgroup to be maximal? If $H$ is your subgroup, do you want $H$ to contain every subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ containing $\mathbb Z$? Or do you want to find a subgroup $H$ such that if $H\subsetneq G$ then $G=\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Do you take group w.r.t. to $+$ or $\times$?

Comment: collect all subgroups of $(Q, +)$ which contain $(Z,+)$, can we find maximal member in this family? I was trying to apply (3); but then the set $S$ should be taken to be infinite so that $Z$ and $S$ will generate $Q$. Through this example, I want to see why $S$ should be finite in fact (3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any subgroup of $\Bbb Q$ containing $\Bbb Z$, consider it as a subgroup of $\Bbb Q$ without considering that it contains $\Bbb Z$.  You have shown that it is not maximal, so there is a proper subgroup containing it.  That proper subgroup must contain $\Bbb Z$ as well, so the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be such a maximal group and assume $q=\frac nm\notin G$ with $m\in\Bbb N$. Let $\tilde G=\frac 1mG$. Then $G\subseteq\tilde G$ (just add $m$ copies of $\frac 1m x$ to obtain $x$) and $\frac nm\in \tilde G$ (because $\Bbb Z\subseteq G$). By maximality, $\tilde G=\Bbb Q$. Hence $\frac1mq\in\tilde G$ and $q\in G$, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $S$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $\Bbb Q$ there exists an isomorphism $\phi$ of $\Bbb Q$ such that $\Bbb Z\subset \phi(S)$. Hence the answer for "subgroup of $\Bbb Q$" must be the same as for "subgroup of $\Bbb Q$ containing $\Bbb Z$".